# nslookup gives wrong ip for my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am having some problem in trying to setup DNS for my domain on my server. 
This tutorial normally works fine for me but when i tried to lookup my domain it gives the following output

> Server:         4.2.2.1 Address:        4.2.2.1#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>   119.100.79.64.in-addr.arpa      name = server.leech4ever.com.
>
> Authoritative answers can be found from:

The server and the address are wrong according to the tutorial

Here is tutorial

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:rR7Z4YU4GI0J:www.broexperts.com/2012/03/linux-dns-bind-configuration-on-centos-6-2/+broexperts+bind&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=mu

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
64.79.100.119 server.leech4ever.com server
```

/etc/resolve.conf

```
search leech4ever.com
nameserver 64.79.100.119
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 4.2.2.1
nameserver 4.2.2.2
```

How to solve this problem guys.....The tutorial was flawless until i did a server restore

Answer (score 1):

If the configuration files you posted are from the DNS server: there shouldn't be external resolvers in `/etc/resolv.conf`. The server is authoritative for itself, and forwarders are configured in the `named` configuration.

```
rm /etc/resolv.conf
mv /etc/resolve.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then check if `named` is actually running and has a valid configuration.

```
ps -C named
named-checkconf /PATH/TO/named.conf
named-checkzone server.leech4ever.com /PATH/TO/YOUR/zonefile
```

Also check your logs to see if the zone was correctly loaded.

Comment: I tried the commands above but now i get connection timed out when i do nslookup .My domains are not propagating although i set nameservers

Comment: It's nice that you tried them. Would it hurt awfully to tell us which results they produced? If you want help you *have* to give us something to work with.